# play YouTube playlist in Blazor using video.js

Tags: youtube, blazor, video.js

I can pass a YouTube URL to a Blazor component and play a video (code below), but when the URL points to Playlist in YouTube it fails to load (unknown error). Is there a way to set the source to a playlist URL?

```
<video id="my-player" controls class="video-js" ></video>

protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender) {
if (firstRender) 
{
  await jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("loadPlayer", "my-player", new {
     controls = true,
     autoplay = false,
     preload = "auto",
     width = @Width,
     height = @Height,
     techOrder = new[] { "youtube" },
     sources = new[] {
        new { type =  "video/youtube", src = @Url}
     }
  });
 }
}
```